# After clicking a href link, generate click event in the target page

Tags: jquery

I have a source page with a list of links. Each link leads to a document with html. Inside each such target page, there's a "print" button. I want that once I press the link in the source page (the list of links), it will automatically trigger the click on the "print page" button.

Comment: Can't be done from code in single page. Next page is new window instance and knows nothing about code in previous page. You could add a query param to the href and check for that param in code in target page and trigger if param exists from there

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you want to execute some function on the target page when loaded, you need to call that function in ready function of jquery. Like $(document).ready(function () { $('your button selector').click();})

Comment: @charlietfl ok, thx

Comment: Nope, I want this not on every page load, but only after clicking the previous link. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @charlietfl comment the only way to achieve this is to pass a parameter on the URL. The source link would need to be parameterized and the target page would need some javascript to grab the passed url parameter (`window.location.search` or `URLSearchParams` is your friend here). You can trigger the click with JS/JQuery:

#### Source link:

`<a href='/targetpage?sourcelink=1234'>target</a>`

#### Target

```
if(window.location.search.indexOf('sourcelink' !== -1)){
    //if you need the value, split the string on '&' and then '=' to pull it out.
    //otherwise, we now know the source link wants to trigger the print button:
    //trigger the click event with jquery...
    $('#printbuttonid').click();
}
```

If you visit the page with a non-parameterised link, it will not auto-click the print button.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Comment: Thanks man! That's great help. And thanks for taking the question seriously and not just voting against the question.